# With Tkinter in Python, is it possible to format a column in a treeview control as currency with red font for negative values?

Tags: python, tkinter, text, formatting, treeview

What I really want is for the imported money numbers to be formatted with red font for negative, black for positive, with a dollar sign ($) in front.

I can't seem to find anyone else struggling with this. I have a hard time imagining I'm the only one who might want to display money columns in a tkinter treeview.

Anyway, if you have any suggestions for how I can accomplish this, please let me know.

ChatGPT suggested the following:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

# Create the main window
root = tk.Tk()

# Create a ttk.Treeview widget
tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
tree.pack()

# Insert some rows into the Treeview widget
tree.insert('', 'end', text='Row 1', values=('10.50', '20.00'))
tree.insert('', 'end', text='Row 2', values=('15.00', '25.00'))
tree.insert('', 'end', text='Row 3', values=('20.00', '30.00'))

# Define a formatting function for the cells
def format_currency(value):
    return '${:,.2f}'.format(float(value))

# Set the formatting function for the cells in the second column
tree.tag_configure('currency', foreground='red',
                   font='Arial 14 bold', format=format_currency)
tree.tag_bind('currency', '<1>', lambda e: e.widget.item(e.item, tags=[]))

# Set the tag for the cells in the second column
for item in tree.get_children():
    tree.item(item, tags=['currency'], text=1)

# Run the main loop
root.mainloop()
```

but there is no such parameter "format" for tree.tag_configure. The error I get when trying to run this code is: "TclError: unknown option "-format""

I was expecting the values in the second column to be formatted according to the format_currency function. I don't think ChatGPT quite got the format I want for the currency values, but at this point, it seems the priority is getting any format to be applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With Tkinter in Python, is it possible to format a column in a treeview control as currency with red font for negative values?

No, it is not possible. You can't control the color of individual cells in a treeview widget.

Comment: I have added another treeview widget to the left of the original table, which contains all of the data with just the amounts. The amounts in this new treeview widget are properly formatted.